# Write multiple Dictionaries into Firebase Realtime database at once with Swift, using childByAutoId()

Tags: json, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm building an app (Swift) where the user can select a CSV file, containing bank transactions.
I want to parse this CSV to my Firebase Realtime database.

The input CSV file would be:

```
amount, label
111, Uber Eats
1678, iTunes
```

The output on Realtime database would be:

```
{
  "user ID 1" : {
    "-M5wUNXgmTuBgZpvT0v-" : {
      "amount" : 111,
      "label" : "Uber Eats"
    },
    "-M5wUQk4wihb3OxcQ7SX" : {
      "amount" : 1678,
      "label" : "iTunes"
    }
  },
  "user ID 2" : {
    "-M5wUNXgmTuBgZpvT0k-" : {
      "amount" : 111,
      "label" : "Deliveroo"
    }
  }
}
```

In this example, I am "user ID 1" and I uploaded two transactions from the CSV file.

I can't figure out how to mass-write these lines into Firebase in one shot.

I've tried to parse the CSV into multiple dictionaries and to write in Firebase as an array:

```
let myParsedCSVasArray = [
        ["amount": 111,
         "label": "Uber Eats"],

        ["amount": 1678,
         "label": "iTunes"]
    ]


self.ref.child(user!.uid).childByAutoId().setValue(myParsedCSVasArray)
```

But the result doesn't fit my needs, as it creates an array inside the JSON:
[Result of the previous code into Firebase realtime database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uy8tN.png)

Any idea how I could upload multiple dictionaries at once, and add a childByAutoId to each of them?

Comment: Use a `for loop` and enumerate through the entire collection and set one value at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it using a `for loop` by enumerating through the collection like below

```
let myParsedCSVasArray = [
    ["amount": 111,
     "label": "Uber Eats"],

    ["amount": 1678,
     "label": "iTunes"]
]

for value in myParsedCSVasArray {
    ref.child(user!.uid).childByAutoId().setValue(value)
}
```

For reference on loops in Swift refer this [link](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ControlFlow.html)

Comment: Thanks, that would work. But what if I have 1000 lines to upload, that would result to 1000 calls to my Firebase, right? Then I’m afraid this isn’t the cleanest way. If I have a bad network, it could happen that only half of them gets uploaded, right?

Answer (score 0):

I use Dart not Swift so I cannot easily show you correct code. I can describe the principle though.

In order to guarantee that all the data gets written, you have to do the set or update as a single database action. Therefore you need to build the dictionary (map in my terms) that contains all your records. Each record has to have the unique key generated by Firebase. 
You need to use a loop to build this dictionary. In the loop, for each record you need to get a unique key by using code similar to this `let key = ref.child("posts").childByAutoId().key`. 
Each call to this will return a new unique key.

When the dictionary is complete you add it as one atomic update (it either all works or all fails).

This Swift code seems to do that for one record so you should be able to use it as the basis for the loop:

```
guard let key = ref.child("posts").childByAutoId().key else { return }
let post = ["uid": userID,
            "author": username,
            "title": title,
            "body": body]
let childUpdates = ["/posts/\(key)": post,
                    "/user-posts/\(userID)/\(key)/": post]
ref.updateChildValues(childUpdates)
```

Hope that helps.

See this link for more info: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write